# Error: Error in Scenario / Assertion failed

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, error, nft

I am doing a contract to Mint Nfts on Tezos on Legacy SmartPY ide (because Tezos tutorial uses it). I already created Nfts but only in single edition, now i'm trying to do a Multi-edition, but the IDE says this error:

```
Error: Error in Scenario
File "smartML/core/compiler.ml", line 2520, characters 12-18: Assertion failed
```

My code is:

```
import smartpy as sp

FA2 = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://legacy.smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py")

class Token(FA2.Admin, FA2.MintNft, FA2.Fa2Nft):
    def __init__(self, admin, **kwargs):
        FA2.Fa2Nft.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        FA2.Admin.__init__(self, admin)

class Marketplace(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, token, metadata, admin):
        self.init(
            token=token,
            metadata=metadata,
            admin=admin,
            data = sp.big_map(
                tkey=sp.TNat,
                tvalue=sp.TList(
                    sp.TRecord(
                        holder=sp.TAddress,
                        author=sp.TAddress,
                        amount=sp.TMutez,
                        token_id=sp.TNat,
                        editions=sp.TNat,
                        collectable=sp.TBool))),
            token_id=0)

    @sp.entry_point
    def mint(self, params):
        c = sp.contract(
            sp.TList(sp.TRecord(to_=sp.TAddress, metadata=sp.TMap(sp.TString, sp.TBytes)).layout(("to_", "metadata"))),
            self.data.token,
            entry_point="mint").open_some()

        args = [sp.record(to_=params.to_, metadata=params.metadata)]
        sp.transfer(args, sp.mutez(0), c)

        editions_list = sp.list([])

        sp.for i in sp.range(1, params.editions + 1):
            edition_record = sp.record(
                holder=self.data.admin,
                author=params.to_,
                amount=params.amount,
                token_id=self.data.token_id,
                editions=i,
                collectable=True)
            
            editions_list.push(edition_record)

        self.data.data[self.data.token_id] = editions_list

        self.data.token_id += 1

@sp.add_test(name = "Non Fungible Token")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    
    admin = sp.test_account("admin")
    mark = sp.test_account("user1")
    elon = sp.test_account("user2")

    token_contract = Token(
        admin=admin.address,
        metadata=sp.utils.metadata_of_url(
            "ipfs://QmW8jPMdBmFvsSEoLWPPhaozN6jGQFxxkwuMLtVFqEy6Fb"))
    scenario += token_contract

    scenario.h1("MarketPlace")
    marketplace = Marketplace(
        token_contract.address,
        sp.utils.metadata_of_url(
            "ipfs://QmW8jPMdBmFvsSEoLWPPhaozN6jGQFxxkwuMLtVFqEy6Fb"
        ), admin.address)
    scenario += marketplace

    marketplace.mint(
        to_=admin.address,
        amount=sp.tez(100),
        editions=sp.nat(5),
        metadata={"": sp.pack("ipfs://QmbR82U2yKHbhjve45rqSF9h25s5aFKhMcpZkLRvXRnos6")}
    ).run(sender=admin)
    
    token_contract.set_administrator(marketplace.address).run(sender=admin)
    
    marketplace.mint(
        to_=mark.address,
        amount=sp.tez(100),
        editions=sp.nat(5),
        metadata={"": sp.pack("ipfs://bafyreibwl5hhjgrat5l7cmjlv6ppwghm6ijygpz2xor2r6incfcxnl7y3e/metadata.json")}
    ).run(sender=admin)
    
    marketplace.mint(to_=mark.address, amount=sp.mutez(5_600_000), editions=5, metadata={"": sp.pack("123423")}).run(sender=admin)
```

My ideia is to do a list of tokens, each one with one ID (token id). In this list will contain all holders (owners) of each token edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things which are raising errors in the contract.

1. The `token_contract.set_administrator()` should be called before the first `marketplace.mint()`, because the marketplace will need to become the admin of the token for minting.
2. `editions_list` should be a local variable, instead of a literal. Since you are adding the elements into it one by one, its values are updating every time the elements are pushed. So, it should be `editions_list = sp.local('editions_list', [])`. Also to access its value, do `editions_list.value`.

So, the whole contract becomes:

```
import smartpy as sp

FA2 = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://legacy.smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py")

class Token(FA2.Admin, FA2.MintNft, FA2.Fa2Nft):
    def __init__(self, admin, **kwargs):
        FA2.Fa2Nft.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        FA2.Admin.__init__(self, admin)

class Marketplace(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, token, metadata, admin):
        self.init(
            token=token,
            metadata=metadata,
            admin=admin,
            data = sp.big_map(
                tkey=sp.TNat,
                tvalue=sp.TList(
                    sp.TRecord(
                        holder=sp.TAddress,
                        author=sp.TAddress,
                        amount=sp.TMutez,
                        token_id=sp.TNat,
                        editions=sp.TNat,
                        collectable=sp.TBool))),
            token_id=0)

    @sp.entry_point
    def mint(self, params):
        c = sp.contract(
            sp.TList(sp.TRecord(to_=sp.TAddress, metadata=sp.TMap(sp.TString, sp.TBytes)).layout(("to_", "metadata"))),
            self.data.token,
            entry_point="mint").open_some()

        args = [sp.record(to_=params.to_, metadata=params.metadata)]
        sp.transfer(args, sp.mutez(0), c)

        editions_list = sp.local('editions_list', [])

        sp.for i in sp.range(1, params.editions + 1):
            edition_record = sp.record(
                holder=self.data.admin,
                author=params.to_,
                amount=params.amount,
                token_id=self.data.token_id,
                editions=i,
                collectable=True)
            
            editions_list.value.push(edition_record)

        self.data.data[self.data.token_id] = editions_list.value

        self.data.token_id += 1

@sp.add_test(name = "Non Fungible Token")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    
    admin = sp.test_account("admin")
    mark = sp.test_account("user1")
    elon = sp.test_account("user2")

    token_contract = Token(
        admin=admin.address,
        metadata=sp.utils.metadata_of_url(
            "ipfs://QmW8jPMdBmFvsSEoLWPPhaozN6jGQFxxkwuMLtVFqEy6Fb"))
    scenario += token_contract

    scenario.h1("MarketPlace")
    marketplace = Marketplace(
        token_contract.address,
        sp.utils.metadata_of_url(
            "ipfs://QmW8jPMdBmFvsSEoLWPPhaozN6jGQFxxkwuMLtVFqEy6Fb"
        ), admin.address)
    scenario += marketplace

    token_contract.set_administrator(marketplace.address).run(sender=admin)

    marketplace.mint(
        to_=admin.address,
        amount=sp.tez(100),
        editions=sp.nat(5),
        metadata={"": sp.pack("ipfs://QmbR82U2yKHbhjve45rqSF9h25s5aFKhMcpZkLRvXRnos6")}
    ).run(sender=admin)

    marketplace.mint(
        to_=mark.address,
        amount=sp.tez(100),
        editions=sp.nat(5),
        metadata={"": sp.pack("ipfs://bafyreibwl5hhjgrat5l7cmjlv6ppwghm6ijygpz2xor2r6incfcxnl7y3e/metadata.json")}
    ).run(sender=admin)
    
    marketplace.mint(to_=mark.address, amount=sp.mutez(5_600_000), editions=5, metadata={"": sp.pack("123423")}).run(sender=admin)
```

[Here's the diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/ceoeQZFD/)

Comment: Thank you, it worked very well!